# Xbindkeys doesn't work properly with keys

Tags: xbindkeys

I've this code in my `xbindkeysrc`:

```
"firefox"
 m:0x15 + c:37 m:0x11 + c:50 m:0x10 + c:55
```

And it works fine! But when I try:

```
"xte 'key S'"
 m:0x15 + c:37 m:0x11 + c:50 m:0x10 + c:55
```

It doesn't type in S, for example, in gedit.

I tried to use `keydown`, it gave me an infinity of q.

Answer (score 1):

Try `xdotool` instead of `xte` if you want to type a capital s (S):

```
"xdotool key S"
 m:0x15 + c:37 m:0x11 + c:50 m:0x10 + c:55
```

But it also depends on your caps lock state or if you're holding down the shift key, for example if your caps lock is on it will type a non capital s, to solve this you can use `--clearmodifiers` for any command. 
e.g.:

```
"xdotool key --clearmodifiers S"
```

---

For clarification, `keydown` will press and hold a key, be sure to use `keyup` after using `keydown` for your other binds.

For example `"xte 'keydown s' 'keyup s'"` will have the same results as `"xte 'key s'"`.